# how to use viewbox inside mdi using wpf

Tags: wpf, mdichild

```
<mdi:MdiContainer Name="Container">

    <Viewbox Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Frame JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal" JournalEntry.KeepAlive="false" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Name="frmMain" Height="1080" Width="1920" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="{Binding Path=CurrentModuleView, Mode=TwoWay}">

        </Frame>
    </Viewbox>

</mdi:MdiContainer>
```

A value of type Viewbox cannot be added to a collection or a dictionary.
Here i am using WPF.MDI.dll which contains MdiConatiner class.

Answer (score 0):

Put the ViewBox inside an `mdi:MdiChild`.

```
<mdi:MdiContainer Name="Container">
    <mdi:MdiChild>
        <Viewbox>
            ...
        </Viewbox>
    <mdi:MdiChild>
<mdi:MdiContainer>
```

If you view the `MdiContainer` in Visual Studio Object Browser, you will find MdiContainer's `Children` property is defined like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<MdiChild> Children { get; set; }
```

This means you can add children of type `MdiChild` to `MdiContainer`, a child of other type like `ViewBox` can not directly added to `MdiContainer`, instead must be wrapped inside an `MdiChild`.

Comment: <mdi:MdiContainer.Content>
                <Button Content="Image"  Height="25" Width="200" Click="AddWindow_Click"></Button>
            </mdi:MdiContainer.Content>
            </mdi:MdiContainer>

Comment: I am trying this but New window is not opening

Comment: Are you asking a new question? Does `<mdi:MdiChild>` work or not?

Comment: that is working but i want to use inside <mdi:MdiContainer> not in <mdi:MdiChild>